# Flex: set another state in the currentStateChange handler?

Tags: events, flex3, state

I have a currentStateChange handler. In that handler. I want to set another state based on a variable. The currentStateChange handler fires but in the handler function it won't change it to the next state. I know when it gets to the handler point the state has already changed. I'm hoping it something I'm missing and not a Flex limitation...

*** state > state2 > I can't  change to state 3 inside state change handler ***

```
 private function onStateChange(e:Event):void
        {
         //THIS FIRES

          if(applicationViewModel.eremndr_mode == ApplicationViewModel.ERMNDR_MODE_LOGIN)
           {
                //it gets here but won't change to Signup state!
                prescreenViewModel.prescreen_state ='Signup';

         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe he issue was an effect that was attached to the transition was still playing so it ignored my request to change the state